# How to trigger the Linux IRQ handler thread again when it finishes if there was same IRQ triggered while it was running

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt, kernel-module, irq

```c
int request_threaded_irq(unsigned int irq,
    irq_handler_t handler,
    irq_handler_t thread_fn,
    unsigned long irqflags,
    const char *devname,
    void *dev_id);
```

How can we the IRQ handler thread calling `thread_fn` again when it finishes, if there was another same IRQ generated and its hard IRQ handler calling `handler` was executed and returned `IRQ_WAKE_THREAD`?

In the above situation, `IRQ_WAKE_THREAD` for same IRQ can be ignored. This is problematic when the same IRQ generation and the end of hard IRQ handler for it returns `IRQ_WAKE_THREAD` during the IRQ handler thread is exiting. Then, the previous interrupt request will be ignored and cannot be processed by the handler until the same IRQ is generated again.

Comment: Race conditions are handled by locks and doing operations in the proper order. We would need full details to say more.

Comment: @stark I think I found another way. Would the above issue be solved if I use IRQF_ONESHOT?

Comment: Since you are keeping secret about your hardware (note, _x86_ has no direct relation to your question in the current form) it's hard to say what you are doing and trying to achieve. In some cases `IRQF_ONESHOT` is correct approach, in some it's just papering over the real issue.